# Fáry's theorem for infinite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Fáry's theorem is a (fairly famous) statement which asserts that every finite simple planar graph can be drawn in a way such that every edge is represented by a straight line segment.

> Does this theorem extend to countably infinite graphs?

A standard proof of this theorem proceeds by induction on the number of vertices, and hence is unapplicable here. I suspect the answer is **no**, but I can't think of a counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this problem was solved. I found a paper proving that every infinite planar graph has a straight line representation.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.1891&rep=rep1&type=pdf